How to fix edges "radiating" when adding a subsurface modifier
I am creating these button models and they look ok as a base model, and they are easy to manipulate this way. But I want to add a subsurface modifier before exporting them, to make them look more natural. The problem is the modifier creates a weird flat area around the holes and I don't know how to make them a little bulged instead. Worse still, when the modifier is applied it makes the square area no longer square, but creates edges sort of radiating around it.




Start with a Plane and subdivide 3 times. Select faces as shown and press i to Inset Faces. Delete the other half of the shape and add a Mirror Modifier. You can easily resize the square with S to Scale and move it around with G to Grab as needed. Then Apply the Mirror Modifier in Object Mode. Then tab back into Edit Mode and select all faces with A and right click LoopsTools > Circle.
Press i to Inset Faces again and then press S to Scale the faces down. Hover over the outer region of the button and press Ctrl+R to add Loop Cuts. Use the mouse wheel to increase/decrease the number of cuts. Select the squares where the button holes will appear and press i to Inset Faces and delete to create holes.
Extrude the entire mesh on the Z axis with EZ. Select one of the Face Loops and press GZ to elevate it. Finally add a Subdivision Modifier and right click Shade Smooth.

You can also improve the Edge Flow of the topology by connecting the following vertices and pressing J to split the faces. Then select the shown edges and press X > Dissolve Edges.

Here's the final topology with and without Subdivision.

Press O to enable Proportional Editing and select a few central faces and elevate it with GZ to give it a nice rounded curvature. Use the mouse wheel to adjust the area of influence.

Here's another method with 4 button holes. I think you can use this same method for 2 holes as well and it is way easier:

You can add another inset into the edge loop between the outer and inner face loops to get this smooth topology:


I see you both went with square shaped holes, would it break anything if I made them circular? For example by subdividing that part of the mesh a little and using "to circle" - alt + shift + s?

@kacpr ah that's perfectly fine. just shape the square into a circle instead with LoopTools > Circle

at the end of the second gif you select two vertices and move them closer together - I'm not sure how you did that, it's not G, or S. How can I do that? I've also tried what you explained with a 4 hole button, but I'm not sure about vertices to connect in that case, to improve the mesh. I've attached the file to OP, if you could take a look and suggest an improvement?

@kacpr I used S then press Y to scale along Y-axis but it may be another axis in your case. I added another GIF on another method to model it using loop cuts and 4 holes.

Sorry to dig this again, in your second method, after doing 5 cuts, and selecting rectangles for the holes, I see the cursor turn to "scale" but they don't actually change size, but sort of move closer to each other - is this "push/pull" ?

@kacpr yes it is "scale" with s. But make sure the Transform Pivot Point is set to Median Point or Bounding Box

Aim to have the same number of vertices in an edge loop around the inner part of the button,(around the button holes) as you have in the circumference of the rest of the button then use the Bridge Edge Loops tool to fill in the missing faces:



The step by step of creating a button with 2 square holes:


If round holes , then instead of adding a plane add a circle with 8 vertices in its circumference.




Tweaking the inner edge loops:

Filling in the holes and adding holding edge loops:


Checking for inverted face normals and applying Subdivision Surface modifier :


Hello thank you very much for your very detailed post and contributing to this community. It is highly appreciated :) But next time please avoid text written inside images, always prefer typing it directly in the body of the post instead. Image content can't be indexed and thus can't be readily found when searching in the future. Updates are difficult because it can't be easily edited in case of mistakes, nor updated in case of future changes. It doesn't follow the fonts and style of the website automatically, and doesn't work with screen readers.
